# How can I update SSAS Visual Studio project from an existing server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas

Somebody made a hotfix on a SQL Server Analysis Services which means I have my Visual Studio SSDT-BI project out of date. How can I update the VS project with the change?

I know only about import from server feature when creating a new project. Delete and create new is the only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would import form server to a new solution in a new directory. Then you can mix the changed files into your existing local project files. What exactly you need to mix, depends on the changes done. I. e. if the only change was in the calculation script, then only the *.cube file needs to be adapted/changed.

If you are not sure which files did change, then comparing the files in both solution directories using a tool like Windiff or Winmerge could help you find the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a create script in SSMS from the live database on the server (limit as much as possible just to the object(s) that changed.   Then in Visual Studio open the code view of the changed object(s) and paste in the script from the server and save it.